# A strange thing about serial communication between Arduino and Matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino

I am new to Arduino and Matlab. Recently I am doing a project with Arduino and Matlab, and I found a strange thing when I try to send some data to Arduino from Matlab.

Here is my code

```
delete(instrfind({'Port'},{'COM3'}))
clear all  

s = serial('COM3','BaudRate',9600);
% set(s,'BytesAvailableFcnCount',10);
  set(s,'Terminator','CR');

fopen(s);
% sss=input('Enter led value 1 or 2 (1=ON, 2=OFF, 0=EXIT PROGRAM): ');
sss=2 ;
fwrite(s,sss,'char');
ss = fscanf(s,'%s');
ss

fclose(s);
```

and i get this

[image]

and when I cancel the comment of the `sss=input` line, whatever I type in the data send successfully. like this:

[image]

I want know HOW can I send a data to my Arduino without any input action.

Here is the Arduino code

```
int incomingByte = 0;

int motor2= 2 ;
int motor3= 3 ;
int motor4= 4 ;
int motor5= 5 ;
int motor6= 6 ;
int motor7= 7 ;
int motor8= 8 ;
int motor9= 9 ;

int matlabSignal;
int motorDir= 30 ;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(motor2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor4,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor5,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor6,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor7,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor8,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor9,OUTPUT);
    //en pin
    pinMode(motorDir,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    if(Serial.available()>0){
      incomingByte = Serial.read();
      Serial.println(incomingByte,DEC);

      matlabSignal = incomingByte;
    }

    /*
     digitalWrite(motor2,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(motor3,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(motor4,HIGH);
    */

    switch (matlabSignal){
      case 1:
          digitalWrite(motor9,HIGH);
          break;
      case 2:
          digitalWrite(motor2,HIGH);
          break;
      case 3:
          digitalWrite(motor3,HIGH);
          break;
      case 4:
          digitalWrite(motor4,HIGH);
          break;
      case 5:
          digitalWrite(motor5,HIGH);
          break;
      case 6:
          digitalWrite(motor6,HIGH);
          break;
      case 7:
          digitalWrite(motor7,HIGH);
          break;
      case 8:
          digitalWrite(motor8,HIGH);
          break;
    }



}
```

Comment: This is no C code! Do not add C (or C++ tag for Arduino language!

Comment: Sorry Ididnt get it. You can send data if you put `sss=input...` and cant if you do `sss=2`?

Comment: just for curiosity, have you tried placing the statement `fopen(s);` **after** the `sss=input('...')` ?